# pyserial slow disconnection

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I found out my pyserial connection is taking a long time to disconnect, not sure why this is, because opening and sending/receiving seems to be quite fast and in line with the baudrates (225bits -> 0.09375 seconds). I wrote a minimal piece of code to showcase my problem. It is running on a raspberry pi3.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime
import serial

def send_and_receive():
    response_line = None
    try:
        with serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB2', 2400, timeout=1, write_timeout=1) as s:
            print(datetime.datetime.now().time(), "Executing command via serialio...")
            s.flushInput()
            s.flushOutput()
            s.write(b'QVFWb\x99\r')
            response_line = s.read_until(b"\r")
            s.read_all()
            print(datetime.datetime.now().time(),"serial response was: %s", response_line)
            #s.close()
        print(datetime.datetime.now().time(), "closed")
        return response_line
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Serial read error: {e}")

for i in range(10):
    print(datetime.datetime.now().time(), '--------------------')
    send_and_receive()
```

This is the output I am geting (notice over 1 second overhead in "closing" the connection):

```
21:31:43.739869 --------------------
21:31:43.744267 Executing command via serialio...
21:31:43.851322 serial response was: %s b'(VERFW:000SR.34\x16\xef\r'
21:31:44.983403 closed
21:31:44.983702 --------------------
21:31:44.987723 Executing command via serialio...
21:31:45.094942 serial response was: %s b'(VERFW:000SR.34\x16\xef\r'
21:31:46.193361 closed
21:31:46.193688 --------------------
21:31:46.197638 Executing command via serialio...
21:31:46.307374 serial response was: %s b'(VERFW:000SR.34\x16\xef\r'
```

If I manually add the `s.close()` then the time will be spend on that call and the connection will exit the with block inmediately.

Comment: Why do you use both `s.read_until(b"\r")` and `s.read_all()`?

Comment: I wanted to clear the buffer, ignore everything after the read, just in case. 
But it does no difference as far as I could measure.